# helping me understand what happens in this loop in java

Tags: java, loops

```
PrintStream out = System.out;

    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        for(int j=i; j<5; j++)
            sum++;
    out.println(sum);
```

outputs: 15. i dont know how this gets 15. i tried solving it in my head, i keep getting 25.

If we ignore the second for loop, and put sum++ in the first for loop, you get 5. But how do we get 15 from the 2nd for loop?

```
PrintStream out = System.out;

    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        for(int j=i; j<5; j++);
            sum++;
    out.println(sum);
```

outputs: 1. What happens if you put ; after for statement. does it stop?

Comment: use the curly braces `{}` for yours and clarity sake please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
i = 0 => j goes from 0 to 4 => sum = 5  
i = 1 => j goes from 1 to 4 => sum = 5 + 4 = 9  
i = 2 => j goes from 2 to 4 => sum = 9 + 3 = 12  
i = 3 => j goes from 3 to 4 => sum = 12 + 2 = 14  
i = 4 => j goes from 4 to 4 => sum = 14 + 1 = 15
```

your second code snippet does not compile as it is.

**EDIT**

Now that your second snippet compiles:

```
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    for(int j=i; j<5; j++);
        sum++;
```

is equivalent to (and this is why you should always use braces):

```
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    for(int j=i; j<5; j++) {
    }
}
sum++;
```

That explains why it outputs 1.

Answer (score 0):

The loop is basically creating a triangular number, specifically the 5th triangular number, e.g. a number of the form `n + (n - 1) + ... + 2 + 1`.

The trick, and the reason that you **don't** see *25* as the result, is in the second loop: it only iterates from the *current* value of `i` up to `5`.

On each iteration of the inner loop the sum is incremented once. Because of the loop trick, the inner loop iterates 5 times, then 4, and so on:

```
first iteration of the outer loop: j = 0 to 4 -> 5 increments
second iteration of the outer loop: j = 1 to 4 -> 4 increments  
... 3 increments
... 2 increments
... 1 increment
```

5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 15

Answer (score 0):

The output is 15 because `j` is initialized to the value of `i` in each iteration of the first loop.

The output would be 25 if `j` was initialized to zero in stead.

Answer (score 0):

To get 25, instead of

```
    for(int j=i j<5; j++); // inner loop
        sum++;
```

use

```
//......here
for(int j=0 j<5; j++); // inner loop
        sum++;
```

What you are doing now is 
`(1+1+1+1+1) + (1+1+1+1) + (1+1+1) + (1+1) + (1)` whereas what you want is `(1+1+1+1+1).. 5 times`

p.s. why the loop in the second code is `for(int j=il j<5; j++);`
? `il` is not defined, and it 'll stop at the `;` even if you have defined `il` somewhere earlier.